# Responsive Website: Faulty Logo and Banner Wrap, Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nav, banner

I'm having a couple of problems with my responsive website. My first problem is simple: the banner is wrapping beneath the logo.

[image]

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is something similar to the site for the [St. Louis Zoo](http://www.stlzoo.org/animals/abouttheanimals/), where the logo and banner image (the turtle) stay on the same row as the page gets smaller. How do they do this?

My second problem is that as the page continues to resize, the navigation bar becomes sloppy. As you can see, the "contact" link is too close to the home, projects, and store links. [image]

I'm new to responsive web design and I'm wondering - can the problem with the nav bar be found in the Global Styles or do I need to create more CSS code within the Tablet Section? Thank you. Full Code Below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Artistic Animation</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="banner">
<header>
<h1>
    <a href="index.html">
<img class="banner" src="images/Artistic_Logo2.png" alt="logo">
</a>

<img class="banner" src="images/Artistic_Banner2.png" alt="banner">
</h1>
</header>
</div>  

<div class="navigation">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-3 col-m-3">
<img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="image">
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vocibus incorrupte dissentiet qui id, 
cu sit etiam iisque equidem.</p>
<img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="image">
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vocibus incorrupte dissentiet qui id, 
cu sit etiam iisque equidem.</p>
<img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="image">
<h1>Header 3</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vocibus incorrupte dissentiet qui id, 
cu sit etiam iisque equidem.</p>
</div>

<div class="col-6 col-m-9">
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vocibus incorrupte 
dissentiet qui id, 
cu sit etiam iisque equidem.</p>    
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vocibus incorrupte dissentiet qui id, 
cu sit etiam iisque equidem.</p>
<p>Resize the browser window to see how the content responds to 
the resizing.</p>


</div>

<div class="col-3 col-m-12">
<aside>
<h2>What?</h2>
<p>This is information about the website</p>
<h2>Where?</h2>
<p>This website was created in St. Louis, MO.</p>
<h2>How?</h2>
<p>Visit our contact page for more information.</p>
</aside>
</div>

</div><!--closes row-->
<footer>
<p>&copy;2016 WEBSITE</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

.row:after{content:"";
       clear:both;
       display:block;}

[class*="col-"]{float:left;
            padding:15px;}

/*global styles*/               

.banner {display: inline-block;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;}

.p1 {margin-bottom: 400px;} 

.navigation {text-align:center;
         background-color:#000000;
         padding:11px;}

#banner {text-align:center;
     margin-bottom: 40px;}

a{text-decoration:none;
  color:white;}

a:visited {color:white;}

nav{margin:auto;
height:auto;
}

nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family:Arial
}

nav li {
padding: 10px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
background-color :#000000;
color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
display:block;
margin-left:30px;
margin-right:30px;
}


nav li:hover {
background-color: #8E8E8E;}

aside{background-color:#19A5DE;
 padding:15px;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:1.1em;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
            0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}

footer{background-color:#19A5DE;
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:0.9em;
 padding:15px;
}

img{max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}

/*mobile phones first*/
[class*="col-"]{
width:100%;
}

/*tablet*/
@media only screen and (min-width:600px)

{
/*12 column grid*/

.col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-m-12 {width: 100%;}

nav{height:auto;}

nav li{display:inline;}
}   

@media only screen and (min-width:768px)
{   
/*12 column grid*/

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}  

nav{height:auto;}

nav li{display:inline;
   text-align:center;}
```

**EDIT**: The reason I can't combine the logo and banner into one image is because I need for the logo to remain a hyperlink to the home page.

Comment: Please check the final answer and let me know if this is the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In action

Both of your solutions in action in one place:

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#banner{
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
}
#banner header h1{
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#banner header h1 .top-sections{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.navigation{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#000000;
  padding:11px;
}
nav{
  margin:auto;
  height:auto;
}
nav ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: Arial;
}
nav li{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color :#000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
nav li:hover{
  background-color: #8E8E8E;
}
nav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 10px;
}
nav a:visited{
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="banner">
        <header>
            <h1>
                <a class="top-sections" href="index.html">
                    <img class="banner" src="https://placehold.it/73x50/000000/FFFFFF?text=Logo" alt="logo">
                </a><!--
                --><img class="top-sections banner" src="https://placehold.it/325x50/000000/FFFFFF?text=Banner" alt="banner">
            </h1>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First problem: any way to get rid of space between logo and header? And is there any way to keep height of banner = to logo? http://imgur.com/a/Y7w8j

(This didn't take your last edit into account, will rework).

Comment: Close, but banner and logo need to be same height and centered with full screen. http://i.imgur.com/R7Kyvvy.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately now I'm pretty confused. I still need the logo to link to the home page (index.html). Also, how much of my original CSS am I deleting? Do I keep everything exactly as it was and just add those two classes? This is the current result: http://i.imgur.com/QkhewBz.jpg

Comment: @HappyHands31 If you are so much newbie, give some 2-3 minutes and I will code it for you. I believe you can copy-paste it to your own files ;)

Comment: I would be happy, if this is the desired result. Please check the updated answer and let me know if the problem has been resolved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102809/discussion-between-happyhands31-and-trix).

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solution for your first question**

Your images and anchors are inline elements. They will only display side by side if the screen size is large enough to do so. You can use div's around your images and give them a .col-* classname to restrict their width using your grid system.

```
<header>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-3">
       <h1>
         <a href="index.html">
           <img class="banner" src="images/Artistic_Logo2.png" alt="logo">
         </a>
       </h1>
     </div>
     <div class="col-9">
       <img class="banner" src="images/Artistic_Banner2.png" alt="banner">
     </div>
   </div>
</header>
```

You have to make sure the images will resize when the screen gets smaller by giving all images a max-width of 100%:

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

This will make your images fill the width of their containing div without stretching them beyond their native size.

Probably you need to fiddle a bit with the right classnames. Also the images might end up having different heights. You can always change the height of one image to line them up nicely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So a couple problems with this solution: 

1.) I need to separate the header from the nav bar.  

2.) Column 1 is now where Column 2 should be / Column 2 and 3 are now both where Column 3 should be / Columns are out of order on Tablet size

3.) The logo is "peeking" below the banner - need to set heights equal to one another so this doesn't happen. 

http://imgur.com/a/UFJh9

Comment: My bad. I forgot the .row wrapper around the .col- divs. The row is needed to clear the floats. I added a wrapper .row div in the code above.